# How can I subscribe to a topic, using a parent class function as the callback?

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a subscriber that is currently set up with a class method that is called when a message is received from a topic. The code is pretty standard:

```
ros::Subscriber StageOdo_sub = n.subscribe<nav_msgs::Odometry>("robot_0/odom",1000, &MyClass::StageOdom_callback,this);
```

I need to shift the callback function to a superclass / base class. However, this generates errors and notes that say that template argument substitution failed. How can I ensure that the superclass function is called?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190920/how-can-i-subscribe-to-a-topic,-using-a-parent-class-function-as-the-callback?/) by [falseazure](https://answers.ros.org/users/19907/falseazure/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2014-08-21

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume `this` is e. g. of type `MyDerivedClass*` where `MyDerivedClass` inherits from `MyClass` and the method `StageOdom_callback` of class `MyClass` is `protected` or `public` (not `private`!).

If so have you tried:

```
ros::Subscriber StageOdo_sub = n.subscribe("robot_0/odom",1000, &MyClass::StageOdom_callback, dynamic_cast<MyClass*>( this ) );
```

If your compiler does not provide `dynamic_cast` you could also use `reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>`. However, `dynamic_cast` is safer as it checks at runtime that the class of the object pointed to by this really inherits from `MyClass`...

Edit:

I just noticed: you do not need to explizitly select the template type (`<nav_msgs::Odometry>`) like you do with `advertise`. The Template type is implizitly selected from the callback argument type...

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [falseazure](https://answers.ros.org/users/19907/falseazure/) on 2014-08-23**:
Great answer, thank you! I appreciate the heads up about selecting the template type, too.

**Comment by [wdudzik](https://answers.ros.org/users/50020/wdudzik/) on 2019-12-05**:
Hello! I realize this is a pretty old topic but this was incredibly helpful to me when trying to create a timer using a parent callback. I was curious why you have to cast this. Can anyone shed some light on that?